# Правильная архитектура калькулятора

Tags: java, android, архитектура, польская-запись

есть четыре поля, два любых заполняет пользователь, слушатель наблюдает за заполнением полей, два считаются на их основе по команде слушателя. Вопрос - как **правильно** написать логику вычислений?

1. Класс содержащий значения полей и их состояние (в фокусе или нет, заполнено или нет)
2. Статик класс, в котором выполняются только вычисления
3. Статик класс, в котором выполняются вычисления и обрабатывается состояние.

Спасибо. Извините за дурацкий вопрос.

Comment: Непонятен вопрос: 1) формулировка 2)что конкретно Вы хотите получить в ответе полностью написанную программу?

Comment: Согласен с Константином. Вопрос совершенно не понятен. Что за поля? Кто такой слушатель? Команда голосовая, программная? Под ваше описание можно придумать с сотню архитектур.

Comment: нет, писать за меня ничего не нужно, слушатель - ..addTextChangedListener, который имеет метод вызывающийся после изменения поля (цифры), в этом методе я пишу либо вызов метода класса вычисляющий значение остальных полей, либо передаю новое значение и состояние поля в класс. Наверное как-то иначе надо формулировать если непонятно.

Comment: В калькуляторе есть кнопка "равно". По нажатию на нее происходит вычисление и выводиться ответ.

Comment: Не нужно выдумывать "асинхронный" калькулятор. Слишком много проблем нужно будет решить, да и не ясно зачем.

Comment: Да я в общем-то уже сделал, просто интересно как правильно, так как код получился не очень, ну все равно спасибо за реакцию.

Comment: При помощи обратной польской записи вы можете буквально за 100 строчек кода реализовать (вполне красиво) калькулятор, который сможет выполнять базовые арифметические действия и работать со скобками и возможностью добавления новых функций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для структуры операций очень хорошо подходит шаблон Strategy, а для вычисления есть хороший шаблон Composite или обратная польская запись.